# Python - increase speed of code Pandas.append

Tags: python, pandas

So I am trying to scrape headlines from [here](http://www.reuters.com/resources/archive/us/). For all the 10 years.

`years` is a list here that contains

```
/resources/archive/us/2007.html
/resources/archive/us/2008.html
/resources/archive/us/2009.html
/resources/archive/us/2010.html
/resources/archive/us/2011.html
/resources/archive/us/2012.html
/resources/archive/us/2013.html
/resources/archive/us/2014.html
/resources/archive/us/2015.html
/resources/archive/us/2016.html
```

So what my code does here, is it opens each year page, collects all date links and then opens each individually and takes all the `.text` and adds each headline and corresponding date as a row to the dataframe `headlines`

```
headlines = pd.DataFrame(columns=["date", "headline"])

for y in years:
   yurl = "http://www.reuters.com"+str(y)
   response=requests.get(yurl,headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36', })
   bs= BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('ascii', 'ignore'),'lxml') 

   days =[]
   links = bs.findAll('h5')
   for mon in links:
      for day in mon.next_sibling.next_sibling:
          days.append(day)

   days = [e for e in days if str(e) not in ('\n')]
   for ind in days:
       hlday = ind['href']
       date = re.findall('(?!\/)[0-9].+(?=\.)', hlday)[0]
       date =  date[4:6] + '-' + date[6:] + '-' + date[:4]
       print(date.split('-')[2])
       yurl = "http://www.reuters.com"+str(hlday)
       response=requests.get(yurl,headers = { 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36', })
       if response.status_code == 404 or response.content == b'':
           print('')
       else: 
           bs= BeautifulSoup(response.content.decode('ascii', 'ignore'),'lxml') 
           lines = bs.findAll('div', {'class':'headlineMed'})
           for h in lines:
               headlines = headlines.append([{"date":date, "headline":h.text}], ignore_index = True)
```

It takes forever to run, so rather than running the for loop I just ran this for the year `/resources/archive/us/2008.html`

It's been 3 hours and its still running.

Since I am new to Python, I don't understand, what I am doing wrong, or how I can do this better.

Could it be that the `pandas.append` is taking forever because it has to read and write a bigger dataframe each time its run?

Comment: Don't call append hundreds of times. Instead, hold a list that has 100 separate data frames, and then finally call `pd.concat`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using this anti-pattern:

```
headlines = pd.DataFrame()
for for y in years:
    for ind in days:
        headlines = headlines.append(blah)
```

Instead, do this:

```
headlines = []
for for y in years:
    for ind in days:
        headlines.append(pd.DataFrame(blah))

headlines = pd.concat(headlines)
```

A second potential problem is that you are making 3650 web requests.  If I were operating a website like that, I'd build in throttling to slow down scrapers like yours.  You may find it better to collect the raw data once, store it on your disk, then process it in a second pass.  Then you don't incur the cost of 3650 web requests every time you need to debug your program.